# Custom error pages for different view groups

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My application has a landing page and an admin panel. So, I want to create different 404 pages for those views. My `views` folder has 2 folders: `admin` and `site` and in them I have `errors` folder with created `404.blade.php` files. In order to achieve my aim I've overrided a method called `renderHttpException(HttpException $e)` in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` but unfortunately it doesn't work. What is the workaround?

**Here's the `renderHttpException(HttpException $e)` method:**

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e) 
{
    $status = $e->getStatusCode();

    if(Request::is('/admin/*')) { 
        return response()->view("admin/errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
    }else {
        return response()->view("site/errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
    }    
}
```

**And also routes:**

```
/* Site routes */
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/menu', 'MenuController@index')->name('menu');

/* Admin panel routes */
Route::prefix('/admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin-dashboard');
    Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@showLoginForm')->name('admin-login');
    Route::get('/menu', 'MenuController@index')->name('admin-menu');
});
```

**It throws an error as a result:**

> Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::renderHttpException(App\Exceptions\HttpException $e) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::renderHttpException(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $e)

Comment: Is this working dd($request->route()->getPrefix()); ? (Adapt it to use the facade) If yes then change if(Request::is('/admin/*')) {... with if($request->route()->getPrefix() == '/admin')

Comment: @CalinBlaga Where should I put it?

Comment: inside renderHttpException()

Comment: @CalinBlaga Please look at the question, I updated. It throws an error... As a result your code given above isn't working.

Comment: laravel version?

Comment: @CalinBlaga 5.4.36

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164612/discussion-between-calin-blaga-and--).

Comment: From where you are calling `renderHttpException` function  ?

Comment: @user2486 I'm overriding the method in Handler.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this in \App\Exceptions\Handler::render

```
if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
    $view = $request->is('admin/*') ? 'admin/errors.404' : 'site/errors.404' ;

    return response()->view($view, [], 404);
}
```

so your method should look like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        $view = $request->is('admin/*') ? 'admin/errors.404' : 'site/errors.404' ;

        return response()->view($view, [], 404);
    }


    $e = $this->prepareException($exception);

    if ($e instanceof FlashingException) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```